# MSI: What is difference between (.) and (.:.) in DefaultDir column of Directory Table of MSI

Tags: windows-installer

In DefaultDir column of Windows installer Package (.) indicates directory should be located in its parent directory without sub directory.
And colon (:) is used to separate the target and source directory names.
Single value (without colon :) in DefaultDir column says that target Name and Source directory names are same.
Then what does mean by (.:.) in default directory column? What is difference between (.) and (.:.)?

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Rob Mensching wrote a number of blog articles years ago that explains this all.  Google "Deciphering the MSI Directory table".  Your specific question can be answered at:

[Deciphering the MSI Directory table, part 5 (the dot, colon and pipe)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2005/11/04/deciphering-the-msi-directory-table_2c00_-part-5-_2800_the-dot_2c00_-colon-and-pipe_2900_.aspx)